# CUDA stream is blocked when launching many kernels (>1000)

Tags: cuda

I found that CUDA stream will block when I launch lots of kernels (more than 1000). I am wondering is there any configuration that I can change?

In my experiments, I launch a small kernel 10000 times. This kernel ran shortly (about 190us). The kernel launched very fast when launching the first 1000 kernels. It takes 4~5us to launch a kernel. But after that, The launch process becomes slow. It takes about 190us to launch a new kernel. The CUDA stream seems to wait for the previous kernel complete and the buffer size is about 1000 kernel.
When I created 3 streams, each stream can launch 1000 kernel asynchrony.

I want to make this buffer bigger. I try to set `cudaLimitDevRuntimePendingLaunchCount`, but it does not work. Is there any way?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#define CUDACHECK(cmd) do {                                   \
            cudaError_t e = cmd;                              \
            if (e != cudaSuccess) {                           \
                printf("Failed: Cuda error %s:%d '%s'\n",     \
                    __FILE__,__LINE__,cudaGetErrorString(e)); \
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                           \
            }                                                 \
        } while (0)

// a dummy kernel for test
__global__ void add(float *a, int n) {
    int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[id] = sqrt(a[id] + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // managing 1 devices
    int nDev = 1;
    int nStream = 1;
    int size = 32*1024*1024;

    // allocating and initializing device buffers
    float** buffer = (float**)malloc(nDev * sizeof(float*));
    cudaStream_t* s = (cudaStream_t*)malloc(sizeof(cudaStream_t)*nDev*nStream);

    for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
        CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
        // CUDACHECK(cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitDevRuntimePendingLaunchCount, 10000));
        CUDACHECK(cudaMalloc(buffer + i, size * sizeof(float)));
        CUDACHECK(cudaMemset(buffer[i], 1, size * sizeof(float)));
        for (int j = 0; j < nStream; j++) {
            CUDACHECK(cudaStreamCreate(s+i*nStream+j));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
        CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
        for (int j=0; j < 10000; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k < nStream; k++) {
                add<<<32, 1024, 0, s[i*nStream+k]>>>(buffer[i], 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
        CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }

    // free device buffers
    for (int i = 0; i < nDev; ++i) {
        CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(i));
        CUDACHECK(cudaFree(buffer[i]));
    }

    printf("Success \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the nvprof results:

When I create 3 streams, the first 3000 kernel launched quickly and then become slow

[image: nvprof1.png]

When I create 1 streams, the first 1000 kernel launched quickly and then become slow

[image: nvprof1.png]

Comment: What's the point of having a huge queue of kernels that haven't run yet?

Comment: a huge queue of kernels will increase performance in some case.  I have a program, It will launch a lot of kernels on one GPU, and then launch a lot of kernels on another GPU. If the queue is small, the second GPU will wait until the first GPU is finished.

Comment: There is a launch queue associated with each stream. You have no control over the size of this launch queue.  However, if what you are concerned about is performance in a multi-device scenario, your depth-first launch methodology is not optimal, even if the queue depth were infinite.  As long as you are launching kernels on one device, the other is idle.  Therefore, a breadth-first launch strategy, i.e. launching kernels round-robin on all the GPUs, will yield higher performance, by getting all GPUs executing as soon as possible, with or without a queue-depth limit.

Comment: Thanks. A breadth-first launch strategy does solve my performance issues. I just wondering if there is a configuration, it can save my time to re-implementation launch strategy. Will this feature be added in the future ;P? (a lazy guy...)

Comment: For the host launch(es) that you have depicted here, you have no direct visibility into the current status of the launch queue, nor do you have any direct control over it, as far as I know.  If you'd like to see a new feature in CUDA, the recommended approach is to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com, with the feature request described in the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are witnessing is expected behavior.  If you search on the `cuda` tag for "queue" or "launch queue" you will find many other questions that refer to it.  CUDA has a queue (apparently per-stream) that kernel launches go into.  As long as the outstanding launch count is less than the queue depth, the launch process will be asynchronous.

However when the outstanding (i.e. uncompleted) launches exceed the queue depth, the launch process changes to a kind of synchronous behavior (although not synchronous in the usual sense).  Specifically, when the outstanding number of kernel launches exceeds the queue depth, the launch process will block the CPU thread that is performing the next launch, until a launch slot opens in the queue (effectively means a kernel has retired at the other end of the queue).

You have no visibility into this (no way to query the number of slots open in the queue) nor any way to view or control the queue depth.  Most of the information I'm reciting here is obtained by inspection; it is not formally published in CUDA documentation that I am aware of.

As already discussed in the comments, one possible approach to alleviate your concern around launches in a multi-device scenario is to launch breadth-first rather than depth-first.  By this I mean that you should modify your launch loops so that you launch a kernel to device 0, then device 1, then device 2, etc. before launching the next kernel on device 0.  This will give you the optimum performance in the sense that all GPUs will be engaged with processing, as early as possible in the launch sequence.

If you'd like to see changes in CUDA behavior or documentation, the general suggestion is to become a registered developer at developer.nvidia.com, then log into your account there and file a bug, using the bug filing process accessible by clicking on your account name in the upper right hand corner.